# Get selected Option from Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the currently selected option. I have this html bootstrap code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="callType">Call</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="callType" name="callType" class="form-control">
                <option value="getBpmn">getBpmn</option>
                <option value="getTime">getTime</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#callType').change(dropped)
});


function dropped(){

    console.log($(this).parent())
}
```

But I have no Idea how to get the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("select").val()` gives you value of selected option. in your code `$(this).val()` gives you value of select box

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#callType').change(dropped)
});


function dropped(){

    console.log($(this).val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="callType">Call</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="callType" name="callType" class="form-control">
                <option value="getBpmn">getBpmn</option>
                <option value="getTime">getTime</option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```